# First React Native App: Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Tags: android-studio, gradle, react-native

## Problem

I have followed the instructions as specified in https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup, except for choclatey as I already have node etc. But I cannot build my app to reach the output RN boilerplate on the emulator(Step 2: in docs) following npx react-native run-android. I have searched for many many hours for a fix but I am not getting anywhere and it's becoming very frustrating. Below I have attached relevant outputs.

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm only starting out so forgive me if I need to ask further questions to fully understand the issue.

#### cmd output

```
D:\CDLearn\ReactNative\AirBnb>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 903 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
11 actionable tasks: 11 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @379b3356

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @379b3356

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

    at makeError (D:\CDLearn\ReactNative\AirBnb\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at D:\CDLearn\ReactNative\AirBnb\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (D:\CDLearn\ReactNative\AirBnb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\CDLearn\ReactNative\AirBnb\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

#### build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.airbnb"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Answer (score 61):

What worked for me on JDK 17, and should for JDK 16 too:

Append the following line to the `./android/gradle.properties` file in your project:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

You may need to stop existing Gradle instances if some are already running, the easiest way would be to restart your OS.

That's it!

I haven't encountered any other issues using JDK 17 with React Native so far

Comment: Thank You!!!! This works, i spent 3 hours reading all type of answers... jesus, next time i'll just use Expo. Can you explain to me what that line does? Thanks!

Comment: This is the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. This should be the right answer!

Comment: worked for me <3

Comment: Life safer, amazing! Thanks

Comment: The error occurred when I installed the react navigation npm packages. Your solution works, thx

Comment: i don't know exactly what the code does. However, it worked like magic thank you.

Answer (score 22):

I think You have updated Java to version 16. Please, downgrade Java to version <= 15. This helped me with this error.

Comment: Waiting for Java 16+ solutions

Comment: Use SDKMan https://sdkman.io/jdks, you can do `sdk list java`, then e.g. `sdk install java 11.0.11-open`

Comment: Answered with a Java 16+ solution below :)

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue today on Mac, as already mentioned, downgrade to Java 15.

I had installed java using `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk` and today I decided to upgrade my installed apps... It automatically updated to java 16 and that broke the react native build.

That's what I did with brew:

```
brew uninstall adoptopenjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk15
```

Just for reference, that's my installed and working version:

```
% java --version
openjdk 15.0.2 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Helpful link for Mac users: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-2FE451B0-9572-4E38-A1A5-568B77B146DE

Answer (score 9):

For your problem the right solution like others already told you, is to downgrade your JDK to 15 or less.

You don't need to cancel it, you can simply decide to switch it.

type in the terminal `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to check your current java versions

if you don't find the right one (<=15 in this case) you can download it from the official site here : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

then in your terminal (inside your project works too) you should type
`` export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 15.0.2` ``   (or your correct version!)

check if you are using the right version with : `java -version`command, if so you should be able to run on the android emulator!

To make this JDK version the default one, you can change the bash file profile by typing in the terminal

`open ~/.bash_profile`

and then add

`# SWITCH TO JAVA VERSION 15.0.2`

`` export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 15.0.2 ``

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (JDK 16) and fixed it with:

- `npx react-native start`
- open android studio and let it clean project
- run app in android studio

Answer (score 3):

This is the issue with JDK 16 please downgrade your JDK to a lower version and set the JAVA_HOME path for the same in vi ~./bash profile

Answer (score 1):

try this command in your command line

`cd android && gradlew clean`

Then

```
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in android/app/gradle.properties. (react-native)

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED. <<---- add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

> sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

> sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencesPanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane

> ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

> `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk jdk-17.0.1.jdk jdk-14.0.2.jdk     jdk1.8.0_261.jdk`

> sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk

> java --version

> ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

> npm uninstall -g react-native-cli