# React native build error when I try to run 'npm run android'?

Tags: android, react-native

**I'm new to stackoverflow, so I don't how to manage question in good way. Sorry for that.**

---

**When I tried to run npx react-native run-android || npm run android, it throws me this error?**

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[:react-native-firebase_app] /home/groot/ALL_MINE/REACT/REACT_NATIVE/EDesign/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Package name 'io.invertase.firebase' used in: :react-native-firebase_app, :@react-native-firebase_app.
[com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6] /home/groot/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/61220cba941701c55a6acecb5d3d8e99/transformed/jetified-consent-library-1.0.6/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
        Package name 'com.google.android.ads.consent' used in: com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6, com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:1.0.0.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
132 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 130 up-to-date
/home/groot/ALL_MINE/REACT/REACT_NATIVE/EDesign/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:11:73-127 Error:
        Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID@value value=(ca-app-pub-1030707148416513~6139129872) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:73-127
        is also present at [:invertase_react-native-google-ads] AndroidManifest.xml:16:13-29 value=().
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-129 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

***How to solve this, I'm stucked here...***

Comment: Read last 4 lines of the error. Solution is given

Comment: I tried that, but it again throws next error. Where to add tools:replace="android:value" ??

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add your admob ApplicationId to the manifest file.

```
<application>
    ***

     <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data  
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"
        tools:replace="android:value"/>
```

also don't forget to add,

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [First React Native App: Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696339/first-react-native-app-task-appprocessdebugmainmanifest-failed)

In my case, the answer by Nicofisi works:

> Append the following line to the ./android/gradle.properties file in your project:
>
> > org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED