# Java module not acessible

Tags: java

I'm trying to run an app in react native and it worked the first time, however it doesn't now, I installed jdk and it correctly.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @2ecd0db5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

    at makeError (/Users/fovu/Documents/React Native Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/fovu/Documents/React Native Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/fovu/Documents/React Native Projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't touch the code.

Comment: It seems that your version of Java and Gradle are not compatible; see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html.  Note that Java 18 is not officially supported at all (yet).  You should use Java 17 LTS ... unless you have a strong reason to use Java 18.  (Java 18 will be EOL in 6 months anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upgraded to JDK 18 and was seeing this error. Could also be a problem for JDK 16+.

I resolved by appending

`org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED`

To the bottom of the following file:

`./android/gradle.properties`

Source for fix: [First React Native App: Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696339/first-react-native-app-task-appprocessdebugmainmanifest-failed)