# React Native unable to compile during npx react-native run android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hey and good day everyone,

when I want to compile and run my react native code in the android platform, it shows up the error as pictures below (app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED)

[image: Error]

The system that I currently use is macOS Monterey v12 with apple M1 chips.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696339/first-react-native-app-task-appprocessdebugmainmanifest-failed

Comment: @SrimuruganSri thank you so much it's has been solve thru the forum above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly encourage you to Use EXPO project manager instead of using pure react native for development and then if you were curious you can eject from it.
Expo give you lot of power with libraries and expo client.

check it out:

https://expo.dev/

Comment: Please try to give a minimal solution instead of changing the project structure / way.